# Is Eclipse Luna plus ADT good

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-adt, eclipse-luna

Has anyone tried eclipse luna + adt? How is it? Is it worth upgrading?

Just found out about the dark theme and it looks really sweet.

And how do i upgrade from kepler to luna? I tried to check for updates doesn't seem to do it. Thanks guys!

Comment: They're free downloads, and you can always unzip Luna into a different location and import a copy of the projects in your "real" workspace. Why not just try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good but i needed a version of Eclipse earlier than Keppler. Plus, the dark theme is really cool. :D